# typedefing a pointer recognized by C to an inner C++ class

Tags: c++, c, inner-classes, conditional-compilation, one-definition-rule

I have a class that I want to share between C and C++, where C is only able to get it as a pointer. However because it is an inner class it cannot be forward-declared. Instead this is what our current code does in a common header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
class Container {
public:
    class Object {
        public:
        int x;
    };
};

typedef Container::Object * PObject;
#else

typedef void* PObject;

#endif
```

This looks like it violates the one definition rule (ODR), because C and C++ see different definition using the `#ifdef`. But because this is a pointer, I'm not sure if this creates a real problem or not.
C only uses the pointer in order to pass it to C++ functions, it doesn't directly do anything with it. For instance this code in the common header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
int object_GetX(PObject pObject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

This as how we implemented it in the C++ file:

```
int object_GetX(PObject pObject) {
    return pObject->x;
}
```

My questions are:

1. Would violating the ODR like this cause any real problems?
2. If so, is there another convenient way to share the class to C?

Comment: Personally I would not have the `typedef Container::Object * PObject;` alias, only the opaque pointer alias `typedef void* PObject;`. Then use `reinterpret_cast<Container::Object*>(...)` as and when needed.

Comment: Do not hide pointers behind typedef.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I agree this would work, but it requires repeating for every single added function, so I'm seeing if we can skip that step. This way also probably gives the C++ compiler the power to protect me from passing the wrong kind of pointer, if it also thinks it is void* then we lose that.

Comment: I would do (still personally) is to match each `extern "C"` function with an actual member *function*, with the only exception being the "create" and "destroy" functions. I would also never use the C API from a C++ program. And I would almost never use simple "setter" and "getter" functions, but rather try to create function implementing a behavior. Lastly I would then scrap my `void*` pointer in favor of the opaque structure used in [molbdnilo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70246554/440558). :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, type-aliasing pointers is usually a recipe for trouble.
Don't do it.

Second, the "inner" class is an overused concept, so my first reflex would be to consider whether it's really necessary.

If it is necessary, you can define an opaque empty type and derive from it for some type safety:

In a shared header:

```
struct OpaqueObject;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int object_GetX(OpaqueObject* pObject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */
```

In a C++ header:

```
struct OpaqueObject {};

class Container {
public:
    class Object : public OpaqueObject {
        public:
        int x;
    };
};
```

Implementation:

```
int object_GetX(OpaqueObject* pObject) {
    return static_cast<Container::Object*>(pObject)->x;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Would violating the ODR like this cause any real problems?

"Real problems"? Maybe. Maybe not.

There is no "mix C/C++ ODR rule". Rules are "contained" within one programming language, specification are written for one programming language. C++ has its own rules and C++ ihas ODR rule. C has its own rules, and C does not know anything about ODR. Other programming languages have their own rules.

You are not violating ODR in C++ - C++ sees a single one definition of Container everywhere.

The stuff in `extern "C"` uses C calling convention, that I could assume that it also adheres to the C language. In this case, you are just violating rule [https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p9](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p9) . Let's say this is like ODR in C for functions.

If not, you are violating something between languages, that would be ABI. You pass the value of a `void *` pointer from C side and your function reads a value of `Container::Object *` pointer from C++ side. That could be allowed by the specific ABI your compilers are using, it could be unspecified. The safe approach would be to assume that it is not allowed.

> is there another convenient way to share the class to C?

C language also offers static type checking just like C++, but by using `void *` you are basically turning it off. Do not mix C++ with C. Just have a different unique name for C side, you will be way less confused.

Also, `pObject` vs `PObject`? Your shift must be fast!

```
// object.hpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
class Container {
public:
    class Object {
        public:
        int x;
    };
};

typedef Container::Object PObject;

extern "C" {
#endif  

struct C_PObject {
   void *pnt;
};

int object_GetX(struct C_PObject obj);
// ...

// object_c.cpp
PObject *object_from_c(struct C_PObject obj) {
    return reinterpret_cast<PObject *>(obj.pnt);
}

extern "C"
int object_GetX(struct C_PObject obj) {
    return object_from_c(obj)->x;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you please explain the violation done according to https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.2p9 ? I don't get the problem.
Also, i'm using GCC/G++, would you know where to look to see if something like that is legal?
I'm asking all of this because in the end, a pointer is just the address in memory of something, so conceptually these tricks shouldn't be able to change it. To begin with both languages allow you to define pointers to things they don't even know.

Comment: `explain the violation` the function `object_GetX` was declared in C side as `int object_GetX(void *pObject);` and C code will call that function. The function was defined in C++ side as `int object_GetX( Container::Object  *pObject)`. This is a violation of the rule - C side will call `void *` and the function was defined with `Container::Object *` - they don't match. `like that is legal?` It's hard to answer definitely on interoperability of languages, because there is no specification that governs that.

Comment: ABI is specific to what you are working with, here's for x86 _on linux_ https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf . And great, yes, you will argue that any type pointer is the same, so it does not matter - great. But programming is not about "making it work once" but about _guaranteeing_ that it will work _always_.  Who knows how such code will react to LTO, or when linkers are smart enough to do accross-translation-units optimization and type checking.

Comment: And anyway, it's for me confusing to use the same type differently in different languages that are so similar. I would use a different name just to have less spaghetti code and so that code is easier to reason and maintain, which is way more important, and using a `void *` pointer just invites trouble on C side. But anyway, sure - your code will work, because pointers are the same size on both platforms.